# URLConnection 404 only on Android not on simple Java

Tags: java, android, json, networking

I am working on fetching a JSON on an externally hosted server. I have written 2 separate JUnit tests to test the network request with 1 in the Android environment and one just running the standard PC JUnit (not run on android).

When I use the non-Android based JUnit (the simple java program) test, the URLConnection works fine and I receive a response code of 200 from the urlConnection and the JSON. However, when I run the same static function on the Android Device, I receive a response code of 404 (File or location not found). The url itself is encoded and does not contain any non-ASCII characters.

For the purpose of not spamming the host server, I have replaced the url with http://example.com/JSONLink 
Things I have tried:
 1. The original implementation:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://example.com/JSONLink");
    System.out.println(url);
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    int problem = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
    urlConnection.connect();
    System.out.println("The error code is " + problem);
    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

At this point, urlConnection throws a File Not Found Error. I have also tried to switch

```
    urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

to

```
    urlConnection.getErrorStream();
```

The Error stream gives me a HTML file which states that the server was unable to locate the file.
 2. Ensured that the Android Manifest included the User-permission for Internet

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

3. Attempted the deprecated apache HTTPDefaultClient Approach as such:

   ```
   DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://example.com/JSONLink");
       HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
       HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
       InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
   ```
4. Use OkiHTTP

Each one of these attempts have all resulted in the 404 error. While I believe I understand what the 404 error means, I don't understand why I am getting it when I am giving it a valid url which can be accessed by any browser (including using chrome on the phone/emulator).

If this problem is server side, is there a way to imitate a browser just to fetch the json?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "The Error stream gives me a HTML file which states that the server was unable to locate the file" -- either your URL is entered incorrectly or the server does not like the request. Check the server logs and see what shows up related to your request.

Comment: I do not have direct access to the server as it is run by a 3rd party which does not know I am working on this. I am developing a proof of concept app. Thus I do not believe I have access to the server log. I am however, able to print out the url before it is sent to the server, and can reach the destination using different browsers.

Comment: "I do not have direct access to the server as it is run by a 3rd party which does not know I am working on this" -- then you have no reliable means of addressing this problem. You're welcome to play games with user-agent values to try to "fake out" the server, but your hacked values may stop working in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step that is always recommended in such case is to cross check the server. And this answer's your question

*If this problem is server side, is there a way to imitate a browser just to fetch the json?*

Yes. You can try any one of these chrome plugins to test your server is giving expected response from your browser.

1) Advanced REST client

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

2) Postman

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop

Comment: This led me to solve my issue! I was missing a header accept: application/json which I added with the line `urlConnection.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");` This was the key!